# Is there attribute for inlining lambda in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, inline

In GCC/Clang it is possible to write for forcing inlining of lambda:

```
auto f = [](auto & x) __attribute__((always_inline)) { ++x; };
```

In MSVC same can be achieved through:

```
auto f = [](auto & x) [[msvc::forceinline]] { ++x; };
```

[Try online](https://godbolt.org/z/GMrxfM63r) above inlining techniques.

My question is whether there exists similar syntax in GCC/CLang/MSVC for regular inlining of lambdas (not forcing), same like for regular functions there exist both `inline` and `__attribute__((noinline))`.

I understand that for modern compilers there is not very much difference in whether to use just inlining or forcing inlining. In both cases it is just a hint for compiler, it may or may not do actual inlining. But as I understand regular inline is a weaker hint while force inline is a stronger hint, not?

So I'm just curious if regular (non-forcing) inlining syntax exists for lambda at all or not?